# Issue with Converting Binary PDF Data Stored in SQL Server VARBINARY Field

Tags: python, c#, sql-server, binary

I am facing an issue with transferring binary PDF data stored in a SQL Server VARBINARY(MAX) field to a client's database using the OPENROWSET BLOB method. Here's an overview of the problem:

1. I initially read binary PDF data from files using Python like this:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    binary_data = file.read()
```

2. Then, I convert the binary data to a hexadecimal string and store it in the SQL Server VARBINARY(MAX) field like this:

```
if isinstance(binary_data, tuple):
    binary_data = b''.join(binary_data)
binary_data = "0x" + binary_data.hex()
binary_data = bytes(binary_data, encoding='utf-8')
```

3. When I copy the content of the VARBINARY field and paste it into an online converter (e.g., https://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_file.php?lang=en), it successfully converts the data back to a PDF file.
   The issue arises when my client attempts to transfer this data into their own VARBINARY field using the OPENROWSET BLOB method. Although the file sizes and page counts appear to match, the hexadecimal representation of the data stored in their database is significantly longer than mine, and online converters fail to convert it back to a PDF.
   I suspect that the problem might be related to how OPENROWSET or FileStream encodes the PDF files in the database. I have also tried encoding the binary data as base64 before transferring it, but the client still cannot read the files in their application:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    binary_data = base64.b64encode(f.read())
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue when working with SQL Server or C#? Do you have any insights into how OPENROWSET or FileStream might encode files in the database? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**My SQLAlchemy code:**

```
        SQL_USERNAME = os.getenv("MSSQL_USERNAME")
        SQL_USERPWD = os.getenv("MSSQL_PASSWORD")
        SQL_PORT = os.getenv("MSSQL_PORT")
        SQL_HOST = os.getenv('MSSQL_HOST')
        SQL_DATABASE = os.getenv('MSSQL_DATABASE')
        conn_string = f"mssql+pyodbc://{SQL_USERNAME}:{SQL_USERPWD}@{SQL_HOST}:{SQL_PORT}/{SQL_DATABASE}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
        engine = create_engine(conn_string)
        
        metadata = MetaData()
        orders_table = Table('ATTACHMENTS_TABLE', metadata,
                Column('id', UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default = uuid4),
                Column('attachment', VARBINARY(max))
            )

        insert = orders_table.insert().values(
            attachment = data_model.attachment_to_hex()
        )
        
        with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
            conn.execute(insert)
```

data_model with attachment_to_hex() method:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional


class OrderModel(BaseModel):
    attachment: Optional[bytes]

    def attachment_to_hex(self):
        try:
            if isinstance(self.attachment, tuple):
                self.attachment = b''.join(self.attachment)
            attachment_hex = "0x" + self.attachment.hex()
            attachment_bytes = bytes(attachment_hex, encoding='utf-8')
            print(attachment_bytes)
            return attachment_bytes
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error converting to hex value: {e}")
```

Comment: How are you loading the data to SQL Server?  Converting to hex and back to bytes looks wrong.  Either send binary data to SQL Server _or_ a hex literal string.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I appreciate your input. To load the data into SQL Server, I am currently converting it to a hexadecimal string and saving it by using sqlalchemy with pyodbc driver.

Sending hex literal string only without converting it back to bytes doesn't change anything data is still in the same format (part of data in sql):
"0x255044462d..."
If I would send binary data without hex it looks like that (part of data in sql):
"%PDF-1.7 %âãÏÓ 1 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Count 3..."

Comment: I'm not sure if this gets at your question 100%, but I think you should be able to use `openrowset` to properly convert the file to `varbinary`. Try something like this: `select VarbinaryContent = BulkColumn from openrowset(bulk N'C:\Data\my-pdf.pdf', single_blob) as doc`

Comment: Post you sqlalchemy code.  If you pass a binary literal in a string parameter it will get messed up unless you have an explicit server-side CONVERT with the correct "Binary Style", see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#binary-styles.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I posted my sqlalchemy code and attachment_to_hex() method that is literally the same code from 2. point.

Comment: @Xedni I think that using openrowset might not be an option in this case. My application works on docker container in different server than SQL Server database.

Comment: Have you tried using SQLAlchemy's built-in `LargeBinary` type when inserting instead of trying to kludge it in with hex encoded strings? (Among other things you're doubling the size of your insert requests by doing that.) [Large Text/Binary Type Deprecation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html#large-text-binary-type-deprecation), [LargeBinary](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary). Does `SELECT DATALENGTH(attachment) FROM ATTACHMENTS_TABLE WHERE ...` agree with the file size in bytes of the original PDF documents?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to solve the problem in the way I tried. In the end, I decided to map the network resource to SQL Server using **Samba** and refer to it as if it were a local resource, where the PDFs are stored.